# How to fix the error: TypeError: logger.logSuccess is not a function

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am developing a back-end service using Spring mvc and the front-end client is in angularjs. I am trying to send a message to the user on the front-end upon successful upload of a file but the error above keeps popping up in my console. Where do I need to correct in my code:?

Java:

```
    @Override
    public CompasResponse UploadClaim(String filePath) {
        try
        {
            ArrayList<Claim>list = getClaimsExcel(filePath);
             if (uploadClaims(list))
             {

                return new CompasResponse(200, "Uploaded Successfully");
            } else {
                return new CompasResponse(201, "Oops! No Records to upload");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); return new CompasResponse(201, "Error. Could not process uploaded document."); }

    }
```

Javascript:

```
uploadclaimApp.controller('uploadclaimCtrl', //['$scope', '$filter', 
'uploadclaimSvc','organizationSvc', '$rootScope', 
//'blockUI', 'logger', '$location','$http',
//function ($scope, $filter, uploadclaimSvc,organizationSvc, $rootScope, 
blockUI, logger, $location,$http) 
    ["$scope", "$filter", "uploadclaimSvc", "localStorageService",  
"$rootScope", "blockUI", "logger", "$location", function ($scope, $filter, 
uploadclaimSvc, $rootScope, blockUI, logger, $location, localStorageService)
        $scope.uploadClaim = function()
    {
        console.log('uploading: ', $scope.myFile);
        uploadclaimSvc.saveFile($scope.myFile, $scope.orgId).success(function(response){
            if (response.respCode == 200) {
                logger.logSuccess("Great! The service information was saved successfully.")
                } else  {
                    logger.logWarning(response.respMessage);
                }
        });
    }
}]);

uploadclaimApp.service('uploadclaimSvc', function($http){
    this.saveFile = function (file,orgId) {
            console.log("uploading file...");
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            fd.append('orgId',orgId);
            return $http({
                url: '/compas/rest/transaction/uploadclaim',
                method: 'POST',
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                data: fd
            });
        };
});
```

I expect a message to be displayed to the user on successful/unsuccessful upload of a file

Comment: Who is 'logger'?

Comment: interpreter is not able to find the function logger.logSuccess(s: string) .

Comment: @Ismail OK, how to rectify this such that the interpreter able to work as desired?

Comment: You don't have to describe your Java code here, if you have no issues there. I think you are having issue in AngularJS only.

Comment: You use both `logger` and `console.log()`, is that normal ? Your error indicates that logger.logSuccess doesn't exist and we don't know what's behind the `logger`

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel what is required to be rectified?

Comment: Add more details about `logger`, we cannot help you otherwise

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel check my edited Javascript code

Comment: Try to find the definition of `logger`, it seems that you're just using the wrong method name

Answer (score 0):

Just like Error say.`logger.logSuccess` is not defined. Maybe you can use the ng-serviece `$log` to instead.